# Details about iphone arkit planeDetection

Tags: computer-vision, arkit

I would like to know from computer vision point of view how to detect plane surface and why Arkit can not detect vertical surface.

Answer (score 2):

The way that ground plane detection works is as follows. A sparse 3D reconstruction of the scene is performed using feature-based Visual Inertial Odometry (which means estimating the camera pose using visual motion combined with information from the intertidal sensors).  Points in the 3D reconstruction (also called a map) corresponds to a feature point detected in two or more camera images. From this sparse reconstruction, a ground plane is established by finding all the reconstructed points which are approximately coplanar. The way this is solved most likely with RANSAC based plane fitting. This works by randomly sampling a small set of feature points (typically 3 or 4), finding the equation of a plane which most closely fits these points, and then testing all other points for whether they lie close to the fitted plane. The process repeats many times (commonly hundreds) until a plane is found which fits a large number of feature points. There is an assumption in this library that the plane is a ground plane (not a wall) so any detected planes with strong inclination angles are rejected. It can do this using the onboard gyroscopic sensor.  The reason why only ground planes are supported is that they correspond to the most common use case of AR (placing virtual objects on a ground plane) but in the future other geometric surfaces will almost certainly be supported.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. It helps a lot. However, I would assume a plane will be exactly the places where it is smooth and lack of features, and thus not enough 3D points. Can they still recover the plane with RANSAC?

Comment: @fireman Features don't have to be 3D structures. A "feature point" as used in VIO and similar algorithms is simply a small area of pixels with enough detail/contrast that it can be recognized across subsequent frames. So a smooth tabletop with visible wood grain, or a tile floor, etc, provides ample detail for VIO and plane detection. Also, techniques like RANSAC allow one to choose what degree of tolerance or error can still produce a positive result, so surfaces like a thick-pile carpet or even unkempt turf grass can be recognized as planes.

Comment: @rickster That makes sense. Thanks. Probably that is one reason ARkit can not detect wall?

Comment: Dunno. I imagine it’s less a question of whether they can detect walls than whether they can detect different vertical plane orientations with enough accuracy to make it worth offering as public API.

Comment: Interior walls of buildings tend to be painted uniformly with a single colour, without much texture detail. Therefore it's hard to detect them using image features. By contrast ground planes such as table tops or ground outdoors tend to have better texture detail. They likely limited the API because computing wall planes wasn't sufficiently robust yet, so would frustrate users. I want to add that there exist other methods for detecting wall planes using back-facing depth sensors. These can work well indoors such as Google's Project Tango, but such sensors are not present in iPhones.

Comment: I want to add that detecting horizontal plane is easier than vertical planes because the horizontal plane has only one normal - the direction of gravity, which can be given by the sensor. Vertical planes, on the other hand, have infinite possible normals.